# How to register keypress event listener on non-root element?

Tags: svg

I've been developing a text editor based on SVG, and I'm now trying to
make it so that multiple instances can be instantiated in a single SVG
document. The way I've been trying to achieve this is to wrap the DOM
representation of each text editor instance with a single parent
element (either  or ), and then to attach a keypress event
listener to that parent element. The problem I'm running into, though,
is it seems that keypress events are only received by the document
root. Furthermore, for all browser SVG implementations I've tried, the
target, originalTarget, and explicitOriginalTarget event properties,
when they exist, are also set to the document root, so it doesn't
event seem like it's possible to hack a solution by attaching a single
event listener on the document root, and then manually dispatching
events by reading the event's originalTarget property.

So far, I've tested Firefox 3.6, Chromium 9, Opera 11, and Batik
Squiggle 1.7, with the following test case:

http://stuff.echo-flow.com/svg-developers/testEventListener.svg

Only Batik works as expected, with the rect element receiving the
keypress event. In Firefox, target, originalTarget, and
explicitOriginalTarget are all equal to the root element. In Chromium
and Opera, target is set to the root element, and originalTarget and
explicitOriginalTarget are undefined.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is relate a keypress event back to
the element that originally fired it. I think I could probably get
this to work if I used an HTML context and embedded iframes; or, if I
used iframes inside of a foreignObject. But I'm wondering if there's a
cleaner workaround that does not require the use of iframes.

Furthermore, I guess as a worst-case scenario, I could do my own hit
testing by inspecting the clientX/clientY properties of the keypress
event, and comparing that to the bboxes of all text editor group
elements. But once again, this seems very hacky, and I wonder if
there's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's better to specify the SVG version and baseProfile you're using in your SVG document.

So far, SVG only support (in the specifications) [those events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#SVGEvents), no key press event. Browsers are a bit ahead the specs, so, lets just assume it's supported.

So, you're using the DOM 3 Event [keypress](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-keypress=keypress) since it [doesn't exist in DOM 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-keyevents).
Looking at keypress event context infos :

> Event.target: focused element processing the key event, root element if no suitable input element focused

Focus is not mouse position. In the SVG 1.1 specs, no "focusable" attribute exists, but you can find it in the [SVG 2.0 draft](http://dev.w3.org/SVG/profiles/2.0/publish/events.html#focusable-attr).

So Batik use a wrong "keypress event" implementation. You could use the "mouseover event" to know what element you're hovering, or try if the "focusable" attribute is already working on some browsers.

Also, originalTarget and explicitOriginalTarget are Mozilla specific, non standard, that explain your results with other browsers.